# Passing YAML into Groovy (Jenkins)

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I'm trying to create Kaniko container inside Jenkins pipeline (Groovy) with inline YAML. Here is the code:

```
import groovy.transform.Field

@Field final String foo = 'baz'
@Field final String bar = 'qux'

void createPodTemplate(String frameworkVersion,
                       String frameworkName,
                       Closure body) {
    Map<String, String> templateNames = getTemplateInfo(frameworkVersion, frameworkName)

    podTemplate(yaml: '''
            kind: Pod
            spec:
              containers:
              - some code
'''
)}
```

However, Jenkins is mad at me:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: There is no body to invoke

I've searched a lot and found out some old examples of how to do it only in declarative pipelines, but there has to be a way. Any help is appreciated! Thanks